# Voltage difference to pool motor

Tags: electrical

At my house the load center has two blue wires going to the pool pump panel. At the load center the voltage between these two blue wires is 240V. At the other end of the blue wires it measures 127V and the 240V pump will not run. The wires have been in place for 19 years. Any ideas what has gone wrong?

Comment: I take it the feed to the pool pump is run in conduit then?

Comment: How far is the distance?  Is the pool pump new?  Any new loads? Anything you are plugging in?

Comment: It is more likely that the pool pump was misconnected between one hot line and neutral wire, than across the two hot wires. You are *not* losing half the voltage along a stretch of wire; that wire would be smoking hot!

Comment: So I assume the wire is in conduit. Let's go with that assumption. I have the two blue wires disconnected from the motor and measuring the 127V between the two wires. I am assuming these two blue wires run directly to the load center and land on the two pole breaker. I can see them terminated at the breaker. Very strange situation.

Comment: There is a second pool pump running the fountain in the pool. It has two yellow wires in the same conduit from the load center and wired to a second two pole breaker. The voltage is 240V between the two yellow wires and at the load center. Pump run fine when connected to these two yellow wires. Long wire run, maybe 170ft., and no other loads connected to this circuit.

Comment: When you are reading 127V is the motor connected or are you disconnecting the phase wires? The reason I ask is because in order for you to read 127V one of the phase wires must be grounded or you are reading voltage drop through the motor or another piece of equipment. Disconnect the phase wires and see what you are reading checking each phase to ground and then across the phases and report what you come up with.

Comment: Yes, what are the phase-to-ground voltage readings on the blue wires at the pump end of the conduit?

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I am just getting back to this project now. The phase to ground on one blue wire is 124.9V. The phase to ground on the other blue wire is 0.53V.  Measurement between the two blue wires is 117.2V, it was 127V three weeks ago. Again, there is no load/motor connected.